# Merge the inner array to the parent array using hash of cakephp

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, multidimensional-array, cakephp-3.0

I have the following array

```
$array['projects'] = [
    'name1' => [
        'task' => [
            'tags' => ['value1', 'value2'],
            'email' => 'email2',
            'description' => 'mpla'
        ],
        'email' => 'email1',
        'tags' => ['value1', 'value3'],
        'title' => 'mpla'
    ]
];
```

Is there anyway I could use the `Hash` class of CakePHP 3 or maybe another class of CakePHP framework to achieve the following result:

```
$array['projects'] = [
    'name1' => [
        'email' => 'email2',
        'tags' => ['value1', 'value2'],
        'title' => 'mpla'
        'desciption' => 'mpla'
    ]
];
```

If you also know anyother package that it can handle arrays and get my job done it will do.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that this can be easily achieved using Cake's Hash utility. You can easily extract the array items indexed by `task` using `combine()`, but not sure how you would then go about extracting the `title` values and combining those with the other array elements using Hash:-

```
Hash::combine($array, 'projects.{s}', 'projects.{s}.task');
```

Perhaps the simplest solution is to use a `foreach` loop like this:-

```
$data = [];
foreach ($array['projects'] as $value) {
    $data['projects'] = $value['task'] + ['title' => $value['title']];
}
```

Comment: Basically my array is way deeper than the example I wrote and foreach is not so preferable option.

Comment: I think what you are asking for is beyond the scope of the Hash utility. Hash actually uses `for` loops to build up the altered arrays anyway, so I suspect `foreach` loops are your best option. If your actual problem is more complex than what you've posted you can perhaps take a combined approach of using loops and Hash methods.